# Watermark for Video in Android

Tags: android, video, watermark, video-watermarking

I have few online videos to play in my android application and am providing video download functionality to the user.

Now, What if I want to add some text or image as an **watermark** on those videos before any user **download** it ?

I have googled it, but got the results for the **Image Watermark**, I have to implement same for the Video.

Is there any library available for **Video Watermark** in android ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is there anyone who can answer this ?

Comment: And you really want to create the watermarked version for each download and also want to basically download the non-watermarked version but before storing on the device you want to reencode the video and apply your overlay. You can not just create one "download" version with your overlay and store it on the server for downloading. Is that correct? So you transfer the non watermarked version to the client and process it there before storing it?

Comment: What's the Process of processing it there ?

Comment: I just wanna to store video with watermark while or at the time of uploading it to the server using web service... So that downloaded video will contain watermark.

Comment: Ok, when the clients upload videos instead of downloading the question makes more sense. I guess all you need to do is search using the term overlay instead of watermark. You can use mostly any video processor, e.g. Android MediaCodec SDK or ffmpeg to do it.